# Avoid recompiling package after rename one table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How to make package (pkg_test) not decompile while rename an internal table (rename table test_table to test_table_new) online to the table that is inside the package (pkg_test).
In addition to this, there is a webservices that consults the package constantly and has it blocked while consuming it.

One of the solutions was to use the command "alter package pkg_test compile" but the problem is that the webservices has already taken the package (pkg_test) and does not allow the action.

Comment: I think the problem to solve is that a webservice is taking such a long time to use and release a data dictionary lock on the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the right way I can think of is: don't do that. If you renamed a table that is used by a package, the package becomes invalid and you can't use it until you fix the error.

Why do you rename the table? What benefit does it do?

If possible, move code - that uses the TEST_TABLE - into dynamic SQL. Doing so, package won't be invalidated, but you still won't be able to use code that references the renamed table. Here's an example:

Create sample table and a package (nothing fancy):

```
SQL> create table test (datum date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> create or replace package pkg_test as
  2    function f_right_now return date;
  3    function f_max_datum return date;
  4  end;
  5  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test as
  2    function f_right_now return date is
  3    begin
  4      return sysdate;
  5    end;
  6
  7    function f_max_datum return date is
  8      retval date;
  9    begin
 10      select max(datum)
 11      into retval
 12      from test;
 13      return retval;
 14    end;
 15  end;
 16  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

Let's see it work:

```
SQL> select pkg_test.f_right_now, pkg_test.f_max_datum from dual;

F_RIGHT_NO F_MAX_DATU
---------- ----------
2018-10-01 2018-10-01

SQL> select object_type, status from user_objects where object_name = 'PKG_TEST';

OBJECT_TYPE         STATUS
------------------- -------
PACKAGE             VALID
PACKAGE BODY        VALID
```

So far, so good. Now, rename the table and check package status again:

```
SQL> rename test to test_new;

Table renamed.

SQL> select object_type, status from user_objects where object_name = 'PKG_TEST';

OBJECT_TYPE         STATUS
------------------- -------
PACKAGE             VALID
PACKAGE BODY        INVALID

SQL> select pkg_test.f_right_now, pkg_test.f_max_datum from dual;
select pkg_test.f_right_now, pkg_test.f_max_datum from dual
                                                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04063: package body "SCOTT.PKG_TEST" has errors


SQL>
```

As expected - package body is now invalid and you can't use it. So, let's switch to dynamic SQL:

```
SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test as
  2    function f_right_now return date is
  3    begin
  4      return sysdate;
  5    end;
  6
  7    function f_max_datum return date is
  8      retval date;
  9    begin
 10      execute immediate 'select max(datum) from test' into retval;
 11      return retval;
 12    end;
 13  end;
 14  /

Package body created.

SQL>
```

See? Oracle doesn't complain although table TEST doesn't exist any more. Package status is VALID:

```
SQL> select object_type, status from user_objects where object_name = 'PKG_TEST';

OBJECT_TYPE         STATUS
------------------- -------
PACKAGE             VALID
PACKAGE BODY        VALID
```

but you can't use the "invalid" function (while the "correct" one still works):

```
SQL> select pkg_test.f_right_now, pkg_test.f_max_datum from dual;
select pkg_test.f_right_now, pkg_test.f_max_datum from dual
                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.PKG_TEST", line 10


SQL> select pkg_test.f_right_now from dual;

F_RIGHT_NO
----------
2018-10-01

SQL>

SQL> select pkg_test.f_right_now, pkg_test.f_max_datum from dual;
select pkg_test.f_right_now, pkg_test.f_max_datum from dual
                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.PKG_TEST", line 10


SQL>
```

One more rename? Sure, why not?

```
SQL> rename test_new to test_littlefoot;

Table renamed.

SQL> select object_type, status from user_objects where object_name = 'PKG_TEST';

OBJECT_TYPE         STATUS
------------------- -------
PACKAGE             VALID
PACKAGE BODY        VALID

SQL> select pkg_test.f_right_now from dual;

F_RIGHT_NO
----------
2018-10-01

SQL> select pkg_test.f_max_datum from dual;
select pkg_test.f_max_datum from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.PKG_TEST", line 10
```

Therefore, see it dynamic SQL works for you. In my opinion (once again) - don't rename tables "just because", you should have a valid reason to do that.

Comment: Don't use dynamic SQL to avoid recompilation, because the *whole point* of recompilation is to help ensure that the package will still work after a deployment. If someone renames a table, using dynamic SQL means we won't know *until run time* whether the change has broken anything or not.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help

I am using a rename because of the speed at which it does so as this table is consulted online by a web service, what I do is first load a temporary table (dws.temp) then rename the temporary table to the original table (dws .finally) that is consumed by the web service.

the other would be to load directly to the original table (dws.finally) but depending on the case this may delay and the requirement is that the update of the table (dws.finally) be in seconds. with the rename I have the table updated in one second

note: the web service consumes the original table (dws.finally) by means of a package so when I do the rename (dws.temp to dws.finally) it is decompiled and web service shows error.

also try dynamic SQL however it is more expensive to develop

Comment: You're welcome. And - thank you for the explanation.